# Which seller is matched to a buyer in the stock market when there are multiple matches?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges

Let's say investor A owns a certain stock and is looking to sell 10 shares with an ask price of $1.  Investor B owns the same stock and also wants to sell 10 shares at $1.  The market maker sets the price of the stock at $1.

A buyer comes along and makes a bid of $1 for 11 shares.

How does the transaction end up taking place in detail?

How does the market facilitate this transaction?  How many shares are investors A and B each left with?  Also, would the answer be the same if the buyer only wanted 10 shares (i.e. a single seller could fulfill the entire trade)

This question is not a duplicate of the one that was marked.  That question asks about orders filling.  My question is about an order that is certain to fill, but what actual trading takes place.  This is not addressed in the answer marked as a duplicate.

My specific question is about what each of the two SELLERS in my example will find in their brokerage account after this event.

Comment: The question that is pointed to does not answer my inquiry.  I added a few more details.

Comment: The first one in the book. The answer is the same for sellers as it is for buyers. The book is synchronized.

Comment: In most US stock exchanges during non-auction periods littleadv is correct: first come, first served. If A submits her sell order first and someone wants to trade at A's price (or higher), then her 10 shares get sold first. If B is next in line, then 1 of his shares gets sold next.  A is left with 0; B is left with 9 and has now moved to the front of the line at the $1 price level. The answer would work the same way if the buyer only wanted 10 shares. (NB: There are _pro rata_ exchanges out there where everyone in line gets part of their order filled depending on how big their orders are.)

Comment: Thanks to littleadv and dg99 for providing the answer to this question.  If you'd submit as a true answer instead of a comment, I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.